# financial markets

Tags: markowitz, financial-markets, risk-neutral

Let's suppose the following model of financial markets :

Market-Maker : the sell financial derivatives, the hedge all the risk after calculating their sensibilities to market risk factors. Thus finally the get 0 money (or eventually a positive value such as bid-ask spread or a business premium). They also provide liquidity to the market. Their framework is risk-neutral / absence of arbitrage opportunity.

Investors : using data-science, or knowledge and economists they bet on the future value of assests such that on the average it should outperform the risk-free rate. (Markowitz framework- efficiency border).

How can these two profiles live together as markets are supoosed to be a null-sum game ?

Does it means all the generated money comes from people from other profiles or other sources ?

Comment: "markets are supoosed to be a null-sum game" is a bad assumption.

Comment: FInancial markets as a whole are not a zero-sum game

Comment: Is this because money is created when loans are created and because employees have to be paid ?